# Telegram : How can i join chat automatically and post message through bot

Tags: bots, telegram, chatbot, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am looking for a Telegram bot that will automatically join a group from a list and automatically send a message.

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: No . It's not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can't join automatically, But you can send messages automatically. like  every 30 minute or every day etc. Using cron-jobs.